# Python - How to remove unmatched rows from two csv's based on one column without merge the two csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files having two columns A and B-

a.csv -

```
A   B

12  0

13  1

14  1
```

b.csv -

```
A   B

12  3

13  2

15  1
```

I want to remove the unmatched rows from both the csv based on column 'A' without merge both the files. The output I need is like after removing unmatched rows-

a.csv -

```
A   B

12  0

13  1
```

b.csv -

```
A   B

12  3

13  2
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
df_b = pd.read_csv('b.csv')

same_values = set(df_a['A']).intersection(df_b['A'])

df_a = df_a[df_a['A'].isin(same_values)]
df_b = df_b[df_b['A'].isin(same_values)]

df_a.to_csv('a.csv')
df_b.to_csv('b.csv')
```